# "The system is running in low-graphics mode" when I try setup autorun numlock on

Tags: graphics, numlock

Ubuntu 14.04.
I like turn on numlock on autorun. I found this recommendation:

> go to /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf and add
>   greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on

When I did it, after restart I've got: 
"The system is running in low-graphics mode". Any recommendation for this error not help me. But when I deleted "greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on" in /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf all become ok! Why? do you know?

Answer (score 0):

Probably be an easy one...

```
sudo apt-get install numlockx
```

Looks that numlockx is not part of the default installation.